# Jenkins declarative pipeline - how to manage Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

How can I have a declarative Jenkins pipeline that is able to manage Jenkins server itself? I.e:

- a pipeline that is able to query what Jobs I have in a folder and then disable/enable those jobs
- Query what agents are available and trigger a job on that agent

Answer (score 0):

A pipeline global variable currentBuild has a property called rawBuild that provides access to the Jenkins model for the current build.  From there you can get to many of the Jenkins internals.

I'm not sure what you can find in the way of agent and job triggering - have a look there are/were plugins that offered alternatives to the default model.